# Deserialize BinaryFormatter data without object definition

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

I have a large amount of data stored inside a binaryformatter dump in a client's program. I have lost the code and thusly the object definition to a hard drive crash. Is it possible to deserialize the data to a json-like format or anything I can iterate through to retrieve the data and convert to another format?

Comment: Why tag it C#? Is the format explicitly tied to a .NET serialisation?

Comment: Yes it is C# specific, why ask questions only for the sake of nitpicking

Comment: This question was asked 5 days ago, and mine is the only response it has received. Most C# questions attract interest but this one does not. You should consider whether you might provide additional information or explain why you used the tags you did, and whether adding to your question might attract more interest. Or not, as you wish. I've certainly lost interest.